# Sorting mechanism not getting applied when a partial view is rendered in a view using @Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a MVC 4 project.
What I've done is provided an **Ajax Action Link** on my view.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Display All Resources", "Resources", "Resources", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "showAllResources"});
```

And on that action link I've rendered one partial view which will display table from database.

**showAllResources** is a div in which I will display the partial view.

In **partial view** I've provided 3 different **Ajax Action Links** to **sort** the data.

```
<th>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("First Name", "Resources", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.FirstNameSort }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="GET"})
        </th>

        <th>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Last Name", "Resources", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LastNameSort }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET" })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Release Date", "Resources", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.ReleasedDateSrot }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET" })
        </th>
```

And this is code in controller action method

```
 [OutputCache(NoStore=true,Duration=0,VaryByParam="*")]
 public ActionResult Resources(string sortOrder)
        {

            ViewBag.FirstNameSort = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder)?"name_desc":"";
            ViewBag.LastNameSort = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "lname_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.ReleasedDateSrot = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

            if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                var tblUser = from s in rosterManagementContext.tblUsers
                              select s;
                switch (sortOrder)
                {
                    case "name_desc":
                        tblUser = tblUser.OrderByDescending(a => a.FirstName);
                        break;
                    case "lname_desc":
                        tblUser = tblUser.OrderByDescending(a => a.LastName);
                        break;
                    case "date_desc":
                        tblUser = tblUser.OrderByDescending(a => a.ReleaseDate);
                        break;
                    default:
                        tblUser = tblUser.OrderBy(a => a.FirstName);
                        break;

                }
                  return PartialView("_DisplayResources", tblUser.ToList());
            }

            LookupTblUserListViewModel wrapperViewModel = Helpers.ConfigureWrapperViewModel();
            return View(wrapperViewModel);
        }
```

What happens is when user clicks on **Display All Resources** link `switch` case goes to `default` and sorts the list depending on **FirstName** column.

> But when user clicks on other link such as **ReleaseDate** or **LastName** to sort data on that column, it does not display data in sorted format but it shows me sorted data depending on column in
>   debugger.

I have followed [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) link to learn about sorting paging and filtering in MVC

What is it that I'm missing out?

Please help..

Thank you.

Comment: Not really clear what your actually getting vs what your expecting.

Comment: When I display my data for the first time it is sorted in ascending order and sorting is performed on FirstName column.
If user wants to sort data depending on other columns user just have to click on that column header to sort do that.
But as I click on column on which I want to sort the data the view does not display sorted data... But when I put debugger and check the output it sorts the data...

Comment: Not sure what your claiming here. The first time you call the page, `sortOrder` is `null` so it should sort by `FirstName` (and `LastNameSort` is set to `"lname_desc"`. If you then click on the Last Name link, it should sort by `LastName desc` (and `LastNameSort` is set to `null`). If you then click on the  Last Name link again, it will sort by `FirstName` (which does not make much sense)

Comment: Ohh right that was a mistake.. I corrected it...
Also I solved the problem...
I forgot to add `UpdateTargetId=` property in those `actionlinks` Oh stupid me!! :) :)